# Passing model object from controller to view which contains inner join in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins documentation, I've done joining in my controller file.

But I want to fetch data from object in my views file. But it shows errors!

My `PagesController` file

```
$storages=DB::table('storages')
                ->join('dealers_of_distributors', 'storages.distributorId', '=', 'dealers_of_distributors.distributorId')
                ->select('storages.*', 'dealers_of_distributors.dealerId')
                ->get();

return views('pages.home')->withStorages($storages);
```

I can not fetch the data from `Storages` object in my views file

My `views` file

```
@if($storages->isEmpty())
    <li>No Storage!</li>
@else
    @foreach($storages as $stg)
        <li>{{ $stg->name }}</li>
        <li>{{ $stg->distributor->name }}</li> //I've done implemented distributor() function inside storage moel
        @foreach($stg->dealerId as $dealer) //multiple dealers for 1 storage
            <li>{{ $dealerId }}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The first error i'm seeing:

```
Call to a member function isEmpty() on a non-object
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Whats the result of $storages in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

we you use `DB::table('table_name')->get();` it will return an array not an object. if you want to have a model object, you should use something like `Storage::get();`

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 5.2 and other versions before that, calling [`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results) on `QueryBuilder` instance will return an `array` not `Collection`.  That's why your code throwing an error when calling this line:

```
$storages->isEmpty()
```

On your code example, `$storages` is an `array` thus not having the `isEmpty()` method. And if you're using [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) the result will be a flat array, thus cannot query multiple `dealers_of_distributors` records at a time.

The easiest solution is by using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent).

First you're going to need a `Storage` model. Within it, add `dealersOfDistributors()` method to define [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship with the `dealers_of_distributors` table.

```
<?php
// App/Storage.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Storage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'storages';

    public function dealersOfDistributors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DealersOfDistributor::class, 'distributorId', 'distributorId');
    }
}
```

Next you'll also need to have `DealersOfDistributor` model:

```
<?php
// App/DealersOfDistributor.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DealersOfDistributor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dealers_of_distributors';
}
```

Finally you can easily query the `storages` table and [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) its relationship with `dealers_of_distributors`:

```
$storages = App\Storage::with('dealersOfDistributors')->get();

return views('pages.home')->withStorages($storages);
```

And now within your view, you can treat the `$storages` data as a `Collection` of `Storage` model:

```
@if($storages->isEmpty())
    <li>No Storage!</li>
@else
    @foreach($storages as $storage)
        <li>{{ $storage->name }}</li>
        @foreach($storage->dealersOfDistributors as $dealer)
            <li>{{ $dealer->dealerId }}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Hope this help!